# Qt4 change linker search order

Tags: qt, qt4, ld, qmake

I have a Qt project which compiles library and application which links with the library.

With Qt5 everything works just fine. But with Qt4 I have one annoying problem.

On linking the application `qmake` for some reason brings:

```
-L<where_qt_libs_installed>
```

before

```
-L<build_dir/library_dir> -lmylib.
```

So if Qt4 libs installed in `/usr/lib` and previous version of my library is there too, the application will link with old version of library what usually finishes with link failures.

Is there any way to change link order except adding

```
LIBS += <full_path_to/libmylib.so>
```

Comment: Does using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` not helping?

Comment: Problem is how did you organized your project. It looks like your library should be rebuild when you change version of Qt.  So your library shroud be a sub project of your application. If you do this properly `qmake` will create `makefile` which will detect dependencies and rebuild library when it will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it with this.

```
LIBS += -lmylib
!greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):equals(QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB, g++)|equals(QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB, ld) {
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -L<build_dir/library_dir>
} else {
    LIBS += -L<build_dir/library_dir>
}
```